# Velocity map imaging

Tags: experimental-physics, particle-detectors, imaging

I am a bit confused about the image reconstruction for velocity map imaging. As far as I understand, at the interaction point, ions are produced in a Newton sphere which gets projected on a 2D screen (such that all the particles with the save velocity get mapped on the same point). What confuses me is the reconstruction of the 3D information from this 2D image. From what I read, one needs to do a transformation equivalent to taking a thin slice through the middle of the Newton sphere (e.g inverse-Abel transform). I am not sure I understand why taking a slice through the middle is enough to understand the velocity distribution of the original 3D sphere. If that original distribution has cylindrical symmetry, it would make sense. But is that always the case? If the distribution is not symmetric, a slice through the middle is not representative, right? Can someone help me understand please? Thank you!